# No function matches the given name and argument types. in postgres with python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

python code:

```
    if aggregate_name and aggregate_value and aggregate_type:
        query = "SELECT SUM(country) FROM soubhagyasalesdata GROUP BY ordernumber"
        print(query)
    else:
        query = "SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name)
```

error:

```
    UndefinedFunction at /api/datasets/reports/
    function sum(text) does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT SUM(country) FROM soubhagyasalesdata GROUP BY ordernu...
                ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here i am trying to query from my postgres database using python
but, i am getting about error.

Please have a look

Comment: What are you trying to do? `country` is a string, you can't sum it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sum a string value, as one would expect. If you want to count how many distinct countries exists in the table for each order number, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT ordernumber, COUNT(DISTINCT country) cnt_country 
FROM soubhagyasalesdata 
GROUP BY ordernumber
```